# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at purple screen after login

Tags: boot, login, login-screen, 18.04, switch-user

Sometimes, when logging in after rebooting or when switching between users, after typing the password and confirming, I get stuck at a purple screen. Sometimes I can escape it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and some other times those combinations don't even work.

I understand that this is a bug in Ubuntu, but I'd like to know if there is a way for a user to work around this bug in the meantime.

---

**UPDATE**. After installing the proprietary drivers of the NVIDIA graphic card it did not happened again! Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Same problem on Dell Vostro 5568

Comment: I think this should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). I think we might close this, because bug reports are off-topic for Ask Ubuntu, even though 18.04 itself is now on-topic. (I mention that distinction because the same on-hold banner is shown whether a question is closed for being about a problem in a development release or closed for being effectively a bug report.)

Comment: The bug report is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1766137

Comment: After installing the proprietary drivers of the NVIDIA graphic card it did not happened again! I will add this to the main text and in the bug report.

Comment: Yeah this happened to me on Intel hd graphics 520. The problem is as of 17.10 and 18.04 Intel graphic update tool isn't available anymore, it has been discontinued, because as they claim drivers are now going to be pushed with Ubuntu. I had gpu hangs problem before on 4.13 kernel with my old laptop. this new issue again with graphics and with 4.15 kernel makes me sad and I wanna cry.

Comment: This question is now the first Google Hit when searching for "Ubuntu 18.04 purple screen" so I'll leave this as note: The workaround of ctrl+alt+F4 followed by ctrl+alt+F1 was what worked for me.

Comment: Same issue here... but the drivers did not seem to help... and the laptop gets very hot once I install them

Comment: Same problem except ctrl alt f4 f2 doesn't work.